# Make toggleable sidebar dissapear when a child link is clicked

Tags: javascript

I made a toggle sidebar using plain javascript and it has a link to a part on the same page but when i click it, the  sidebar still over shadows the target data.how can I remove it?

```
<div class="container sidebar">
 <h4>Quick Links</h4>
 <ul>
  <li><a href="#">Log in </a></li>
  <li><a href="#">register</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">services</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
 </ul>
 <h4>Contacts</h4>
 <ul>
  <li><a href="tel:+256751224583"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i>+256 751224583</a>
  <li><a href="#contacts"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>alfredkhan@gmail.com</a>
  <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook"></i>alfredkhan</a>
 </ul>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
document.querySelector('.fa-bars').addEventListener('click',toggle);
 function toggle() {
const sidebar=document.querySelector('.sidebar');
if(sidebar.style.display==='none') {
sidebar.style.display='block';
} else {
sidebar.style.display='none';
}
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution, create another function that looks at all links using `querySelectorAll`

Loop through each link and use your same toggle function to close the sidebar when a link is clicked like this:

```
for (var i=0; i < links.length; i++) {
    links[i].addEventListener('click',toggle);
}
```

Run the snippet below to see it in action.

```js
const sidebar = document.querySelector('.sidebar');

document.querySelector('.fa-bars').addEventListener('click',toggle);

function toggle() {
if(sidebar.style.display==='none') {
sidebar.style.display='block';
} else {
sidebar.style.display='none';
}
};

var links = document.querySelectorAll('li a');

for (var i=0; i < links.length; i++) {
    links[i].addEventListener('click',toggle);
}
```

```html
<div class="container sidebar">
 <h4>Quick Links</h4>
 <ul>
  <li><a onclick="close();" href="#">Log in </a></li>
  <li><a onclick="close();" href="#">register</a></li>
  <li><a onclick="close();" href="#">services</a></li>
  <li><a onclick="close();" href="#">About us</a></li>
 </ul>
 <h4>Contacts</h4>
 <ul>
  <li><a onclick="close();" href="tel:+256751224583"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i>+256 751224583</a>
  <li><a onclick="close();" href="#contacts"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>alfredkhan@gmail.com</a>
  <li><a onclick="close();" href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook"></i>alfredkhan</a>
 </ul>
</div>

<button class="fa-bars">toggle</button>
```